# How to include HTML partials using Vite?

Tags: templates, rollup, rollupjs, vite

Is it possible to include snippets of shared HTML using Vite (vanilla)? I'm looking for a way to have the HTML prerendered without injecting via JS.

Something like:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    { include 'meta-tags' }
  </head>
  <body> 
    { include 'nav' }
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[`vite-plugin-handlebars`](https://github.com/alexlafroscia/vite-plugin-handlebars) was the solution I was looking for. Partials were super easy to set up with this package:

Setup:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { resolve } from 'path';
import handlebars from 'vite-plugin-handlebars';

export default {
  plugins: [
    handlebars({
      partialDirectory: resolve(__dirname, 'partials'),
    }),
  ],
};
```

File where you want to include partial:

```html
<!-- index.html -->
{{> header }}

<h1>The Main Page</h1>
```

Rendered output:

```html
<header><a href="/">My Website</a></header>

<h1>The Main Page</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`vite-plugin-html`](https://github.com/vbenjs/vite-plugin-html) that enables [EJS templates](https://ejs.co/) in `index.html`:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { createHtmlPlugin } from 'vite-plugin-html'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    createHtmlPlugin({
      entry: 'main.js',

      /**
       * Data that needs to be injected into the index.html ejs template
       */
      inject: {
        data: {
          metaTags: `<meta charset="UTF-8" />
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`,
          nav: `<nav>
            <a href="https://google.com">Google</a> | 
            <a href="https://apple.com">Apple</a>
          </nav>`,
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
})
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
  <head>
    <%- metaTags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%- nav %>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <body>
</html>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-prerender-index-html-with-injected-data?file=vite.config.js)

Comment: why does it need a `entry` js?